# Writing user input to a text file in python

Tags: python

Ok here we go, i've been looking at this all day and i'm going crazy, i thought i'd done the hard bit but now i'm stuck. I'm making a highscores list for a game and i've already created a binary file that store the scores and names in order. Now i have to do the same thing but store the scores and names in a text file.

This is the binary file part but i have no idea where to start with using a text file.

```
def newbinfile():

    if not os.path.exists('tops.dat'):
        hs_data = []
        make_file = open('tops.dat', 'wb')
        pickle.dump(hs_data, make_file)
        make_file.close     
    else:
        None


def highscore(score, name):

    entry = (score, name)

    hs_data = open('tops.dat', 'rb')
    highsc = pickle.load(hs_data)
    hs_data.close()

    hs_data = open('tops.dat', 'wb+')
    highsc.append(entry)
    highsc.sort(reverse=True)
    highsc = highsc[:5]
    pickle.dump(highsc, hs_data)
    hs_data.close()

    return highsc
```

Any help on where to start with this would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: what is the point of the `else: None` line?

Comment: also you forgot the parens after `make_file.close` **()**

Comment: I'm fairly new to this and the 'else: None' i put there because i thought it would throw up an error. I see i forgot the () but it didnt cause the the program to fail.

Comment: the `else: None` actually doesn't do anything, removing it will change nothing about the program.  If you meeant to signal an error, you should `raise` an exception of some kind.  I'm not sure what the error in this case would be though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python has built-in methods for writing to files that you can use to write to a text file.

```
writer = open("filename.txt", 'w+')
# w+ is the flag for overwriting if the file already exists
# a+ is the flag for appending if it already exists

t = (val1, val2) #a tuple of values you want to save

for elem in t:
    writer.write(str(elem) + ', ')
writer.write('\n') #the write function doesn't automatically put a new line at the end

writer.close()
```

Comment: So with this you can write information stored in tuples to a text file. Awesome! Cheers

Answer (score 3):

I think you should use the `with` keywords.

You'll find examples corresponding to what you want to do [here](http://preshing.com/20110920/the-python-with-statement-by-example).

```
with open('output.txt', 'w') as f:
    for l in ['Hi','there','!']:
        f.write(l + '\n')
```

Comment: Ah ok i'll do a bit of reading, thanks for help. Sorry i can't green light all these solutions.

Comment: Not that I care about the green tick but `with` is the way to go.

Comment: So your with statement here writes hi - there - ! into output.txt? If this is the case can i use it to write from nested lists into the text file also?

Answer (score 2):

Start here:

```
>>> mydata = ['Hello World!', 'Hello World 2!']
>>> myfile = open('testit.txt', 'w')
>>> for line in mydata:
...     myfile.write(line + '\n')
... 
>>> myfile.close()           # Do not forget to close
```

***EDIT :***

Once you are familiar with this, use the `with` keyword, which guaranties the closure when the file handler gets out of scope:

```
>>> with open('testit.txt', 'w') as myfile:
...     for line in mydata:
...         myfile.write(line + '\n')
...
```

Comment: I recommend using the `with` keyword instead of just opening the file. That ensures it will be closed properly without need a `try-except` block.

Comment: I agree, but form the pedagogic point of view, for a beginner, I find it good to start `with` things that are explicit... Then go into more advanced pythonic stuffs.